# Can't delete Kubernetes Service - Azure

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-container-service

Didn't provision properly. In a provisioning state of failed. I get the followoing when trying to delete from portal/Azure CLI:

Failed to delete container service 'GTK8s'. Error: 'autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=401 Code="InvalidAuthenticationToken" Message="The received access token is not valid: at least one of the claims 'puid' or 'altsecid' or 'oid' should be present. If you are accessing as application please make sure service principal is properly created in the tenant."'

I can't see a service principal relating to this application in Azure AD.

Comment: i'd suggest restarting browser in incognito mode

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Executed the delete operation in incognito mode. It said the delete was successful, but the resource still seems to be there.

Comment: just wait, it will be gone

Comment: It still allows me to access the resource, and allows to me try to delete it again, which causes the same (original) error. Is this normal behaviour in your experience?

Comment: Now i'm also getting the same error in incognito mode.

Comment: try using another browser\another pc\create another user with enough rights

Comment: I've already tried this from 2 PCs. The user I'm using is the subscription owner.

Comment: try deleting the resource group

Comment: Tried that a couple of times. It just times out.

Comment: raise a support ticket

Comment: I'm on the basic plan. I'm only using it to lab for 70-533. I just want to delete it so I'm not getting charged for it. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: well, if the above didnt help only support can help you

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the resource group worked for me. Thx for the suggestion @4c74356b41

Comment: Link to the user directly by doing `[4c74356b41](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6067741/4c74356b41)` -> [4c74356b41](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6067741/4c74356b41). That gives proper attribution. Even better, make this a community wiki. Also, @ doesn't work in answers.